# How to specify "element(by.id" or "element(by.css" in Ember.js using Protractor

Tags: ember.js, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

New to ember.js -- used http://yoember.com/ to create a Demo ember.js site. I'm trying to figure out how to use Protractor to test certain elements, but I'm encountering issues specifying them.

Most, but not all, elements (buttons, text areas, etc) have a serialized id value: `id='ember###'` that changes every time the page is reloaded, which makes it impossible to indicate some elements in Protractor (like, `element(by.id('ember557')).sendKeys('foo');`).

Running a command like the one above will return the error: `Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, *[id="ember557"])`, which is due to the 3-digit id value changing.

In my demo app, I was able to go into the `/app/templates/components/` file for that page and manually add something like `id='name'` into the handlebars input and was able to successfully find and test that element in Protractor.

This isn't ideal though, and I'd like to find a way to test sites that I don't have the ability to modify the html of.

Can anyone help me wrap my head around this? Thanks.

Comment: Could you please elaborate why you want to use Protractor? I'm not used to it, but they are saying it's for Angular. Ember itself has very good testing support build in and it's covered well by official guide.

Comment: I'm using Protractor as a research project for work. We mainly use Protractor and I was tasked with seeing how it might operate with Ember. I'm just attempting to see what is and is not possible using Protractor to test Ember.js. I've encountered a wall, and wanted to ask on Stackoverflow to see if I could find any insight.

I have only glanced at Ember built in testing, but it seemed like I couldn't be able to test sites not hosted locally. Is that true?

Comment: You can use `CSS selector` and `XPath` to locate element on page, not only `ID`.  Combine to use `CSS selector` and `XPath`, it can find any element on page, and Protractor support both of them. So using Protractor to test `Ember.js` web app  is no problem.

Comment: @yong Unfortunately css and xpath also come up with the same 'ember###' value.

Comment: for example the page have two card with different title, but all elements inside card has same structure and has same class, you can locator the container node of card by card title via using xpath by text, then use the container node as parent node to find inside element by css or xpath, like `element(by.xpath('xpath of container node')).element(by.css('css/xpath of inside element'))`.  I think this approach should not resolve all situations and will need more effort.  The better way is add special ID/Class at key node, like container node of card, table, section of form fields etc.

Comment: I don't know if Protractor supports it, but a best practice in ember is to use data attributes as test selectors and not reuse ID or css classes. ember-test-selectors adds some additional features making that approach easier and allowing to remove test selectors in production build. I have the feeling that it's about two questions: a) How should I select my elements in testing? b) How could I integrate Protactor into my ember stack.

Comment: Ember inserts its own ember#### values for ids. You should not use these. Put classes or data attributes on elements for testing by simply adding class="whatever" or data-whatever to your elements / components.

Comment: have a look at [`ember-test-selectors`](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-test-selectors)